# Base64 decoding and encoding give different results

Tags: python, encoding, base64, decoding

I have the two following encoded string :

```
base64_str1 = 'eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjozNiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MX0%3D'
base64_str2 = 'eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MCwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjowLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ%3D%3D'
```

Using [Base64 online decoder/encoder](https://www.base64decode.org/) , the results are as follow (which are the right results) :

```
base64_str1_decoded = '{"section_offset":2,"items_offset":36,"version":1}7'
base64_str2_decoded = '{"section_offset":0,"items_offset":0,"version":1}'
```

However, when I tried to encode `base64_str1_decoded` or `base64_str2_decoded` back to Base64, I'm not able to obtain the initial base64 strings.

For instance, the ouput for the following code :

```
base64_str2_decoded = '{"section_offset":0,"items_offset":0,"version":1}'
recoded_str2 = base64.b64encode(bytes(base64_str2_decoded, 'utf-8'))
print(recoded_str2)

# output = b'eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MCwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjowLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ=='
# expected_output = eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MCwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjowLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ%3D%3D
```

I tried changing the encoding scheme but can't seem to make it work.

Comment: In the future, it may be more useful to use something like Code Sand Box to test your encoding and show a complete example when possible. The online encoder mentioned is very helpful but it's not a 1:1 comparison for output as shown buy it stripping the b' from the final output, which is used in Python to denote that the string is actually a bytes object. I put together a simple example here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/peaceful-ramanujan-w6hk52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that extra `7` at the end of `base64_str1_decoded`?  That's because your input strings are incorrect.  They have escape codes required for URLs.  `%3D` is an escape code for `=`, which is what should be entered into the online decoder instead.  You'll notice the 2nd string in the decoder has an extra `ÃÜ` on the next line you haven't shown due to using `%3D%3D` instead of `==`.  That online decoder is allowing invalid base64 to be decoded.

To correctly decode in Python use [`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) on the string to remove the escaping first:

```py
import base64
import urllib.parse

base64_str1 = 'eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjozNiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MX0%3D'
base64_str2 = 'eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MCwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjowLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ%3D%3D'

# Demonstrate Python decoder detects invalid B64 encoding
try:
    print(base64.b64decode(base64_str1))
except Exception as e:
    print('Exception:', e)
try:
    print(base64.b64decode(base64_str2))
except Exception as e:
    print('Exception:', e)

# Decode after unquoting...
base64_str1_decoded = base64.b64decode(urllib.parse.unquote(base64_str1))
base64_str2_decoded = base64.b64decode(urllib.parse.unquote(base64_str2))
print(base64_str1_decoded)
print(base64_str2_decoded)

# See valid B64 encoding.
recoded_str1 = base64.b64encode(base64_str1_decoded)
recoded_str2 = base64.b64encode(base64_str2_decoded)
print(recoded_str1)
print(recoded_str2)
```

Output:

```
Exception: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (69) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4
Exception: Incorrect padding
b'{"section_offset":2,"items_offset":36,"version":1}'
b'{"section_offset":0,"items_offset":0,"version":1}'
b'eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjozNiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MX0='
b'eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MCwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjowLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ=='
```

Note that the `b''` notation is Python's indication that the object is a byte string as opposed to a Unicode string and is not part of the string itself.